# Displaying images from an array of drawtables in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and experimenting with it.I have 3 pngs.I am setting the first png using
ImageView.setImageResource()
Now what I have to do is:
When the user touches the png on screen I have to display the remaing pngs as well.
I have tried :

```
for(int i =0;i<treeArray.length;i++)
{ 
    image1.setImageResource(treeArray[i]);
    print the value i
}
```

Now the problem is the the value of i is incrementing perfectly but I cannot see the respective images on the emulator.
I have tried many other ways by searching on google but the problem still persists

Comment: image1.setImageResource(treeArray[i]); Thread.sleep(3000); Try this in try catch block and set onclicklistener of imageview

Comment: None of the images are showing at all?

Comment: No,when I run the program,I can see the first image.in clicking it I can see the second image..but after that only loop counter increments but the image  does not

Answer (score 0):

Try this...Add function touch listener for the 1st image which is already stored and then load other images.

```
       first_image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //load other images here.
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: -I have done this only but the problem is that I am able to load the other images properly.I am looping through the array of images but the images are getting loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code really helpful :

```
for(int i =0;i<treeArray.length;i++)
    { 

        mHandler.sendMessage(i);

    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message){

            switch (message.what){

            case SOME_OPERATION:
                mHandler.postDelay(new Runnable(){
                     image1.setImageResource(treeArray[message.what]);
                },1000);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
```